# Why is $\lim\limits_{x= 0}a^{x}=1$?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\lim a^{x}=g$. Then 
\begin{align}
     \ln{\lim{a^{x}}}&=\ln{g}\\
     \lim{\ln{a^{x}}}&=\ln{g}\\
     \lim{x\cdot{\ln{a}}}&=\ln{g}\\
     \ln{a}\cdot{\lim{x}}&=\ln{g}\\
     0&=\ln{g}\\
     e^{0}&=e^{\ln{g}}\\
     1&=g.
\end{align}

But this seems like it's begging the question since we're assuming that $e^{0}=1$, which is a particular instance of what we're trying to prove; namely, $a^{0}=1$.

---

***Remark.*** Note that the notation $\lim_{x=a}f(x)$ is justified per the following:

We call the number $g$ the limit of a function $f$ at point $a$ if for every sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ converging to $a$, with it's terms different from $a$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_{n})=g$ holds.

Comment: Maybe $a^0 =1$ by the laws of exponents when $a\not = 0$? No need for limits here.

Comment: Note that your line 1 assumes $g>0$, and your line 2 assumes the function $x\mapsto a^x$ is continuous at $x=0$. These are both true (for $a>0$, anyway), but those assumptions *are* implicit nonetheless.

Comment: $a^0$ by definition (for $a\neq0$). The question title asks if $a^x$ is continuous in $x=0$.

Comment: $a^0=1$ by definition for $a=0$ too. But in that case it's _not_ continuous there.

Comment: You are not trying to prove that $a^0=1$ (this is true by definition). You are trying to show that $a^x\to 1$ as $x\to 0$. This requires a proper definition of $a^x $ for $a>0$ and all real $x$.

Comment: @AlexD Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've proven that this limit actually exists, let $\displaystyle L = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}a^x$.  Since $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is a continuous function,  we should have $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sqrt{a^x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} a^{x/2} = \sqrt{L}$.

But this limit is equal to the original, namely $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} a^x = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} a^{x/2}$, which means $L = \sqrt{L}$, or in other words $L^2 - L = 0$.  So $L = 0$ or $L=1$.

If you can reason that $L \neq 0$, you're done.

Comment: Couldn't you say $\forall{a}:|a|>0,\ a^{x}\not=0\implies \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}a^x\not=0$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\forall a\neq 0\implies a^0=1$.

Maybe it should be more interesting to consider why

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}x^{x}=1$$